# What is a formula to remove the whitespace from an Excel cell when trim doesn't work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of Excel data that I copied from an html table in Internet Explorer. A column of table values all seem to have a space at the end of them, but `Trim` won't remove it. When I paste-special the value of the result of the `Trim` function, it still has the whitespace on the end.

Could it be some other sort of whitespace character that `Trim` doesn't remove?

Comment: If you look at it in the mode where you can see what kind of characters are there, what type of character is not being removed?

Comment: if you do =LEN(CELL) then what does it return?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the ASCII number of the last character?  Use `=CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))` (assuming `A1` contians the problematic text) to see it.  Space is 32, Tab is 9, and new line characters are 10 and 13.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, the result of that function is 160

Comment: @kobaltz, =LEN(CELL) returns 9. The cell value is (without the double quotes) "010-0000 ", but trim doesn't seem to remove the last character. The copy and paste to put the value here may well be modified to be a space by my browser, or some other means...

Comment: @soandos, I don't know what mode you mean - Can you provide a link with details?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Character 160 is a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), a character designed to look like a space but still be part of the word, forcing the adjacent words to stay together.  You can convert them to regular spaces and then use trim.

Assuming the text is in `A1`, use:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), " "))
```

Comment: +1. [This link is a useful reference](http://www.rondebruin.nl/clean.htm). Quite often `CLEAN` , `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` are all needed for dealing with strings

Answer (score 1):

If it just has one space and let's assume that the column is A.

```
A1= "CELL A1 "
A2= "CELL A2 "

Then B1 would be =LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)
Then B2 would be =LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-1)
```

Comment: If that was what it was, then trim would work...

Comment: And from what the comments indicate, this would have worked just as well.

Comment: Because you got lucky. The could have been more than one character there, and you never would have known. In addition, the other answer deals with it no matter where in the cell it occurs, making it a much better general answer in any case.

Comment: Unless it had something like ASCII 160 and ASCII 161. Where as, if you know the length of each string and you see that it's one off from what is expected, personally I do not see the issue with this. I'm open to try and understand your view, but both solutions do have their limitations in different environments.

Comment: Agreed. I guess I like the other answer more because he identified the problem, and then solved it. You have a solution to something that solves similar problems. I see your point though, +1.

Comment: This only works though where the issue always occurs at the end of the string AND if the string is known to be problematic (else you are truncating a good string). Much better to diagnose the root cause

Comment: The only way that they found the problem child was by doing =CODE(RIGHT(A1,1)) which returned 160. I still do not see how it can be justified that one way is better than the other. The root cause of the problem was that by copying from a website into excel generated an extra "space" at the end of each cell. My solution replicates the cell without the last character. Based on their initial issue, I promptly provided a solution with no guess work or luck, because I understood the root cause of their issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it would be easier to select the entire worksheet and use Replace (Ctrl+H) to replace every non-break space (NBSP) with a space.  This still leaves spaces at the end of cells but avoid removing NBSPs from the middle of cells.  You still need Trim but that is easier than TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(...)).

I thought I would be able to enter a NBSP using Alt+160 but it did not work for me.  I had to use Insert Symbol to place a NBSP into a cell, copy it out of there and drop it into the Find what field.

With Insert Symbol, NBSP is the empty cell on the third line under 4.

If this is a repeating problem, you could use the macro recorder to save the Replace.  However, it might be better to write a macro which uses FIND to locate NBSP anywhere within any string and either replace it with space or delete it according to its position within the string.  This macro would need to loop until FIND fails.

Comment: You can type NBSP with Alt+0160.  One to three-digit numbers are ASCII, four-digit numbers are unicode.

Comment: I gave up as soon as it didn't work.  Your comment persuaded me to try again.  I had forgotten it only worked with the numeric pad which on a laptop is in the middle of the keyboard.  I will try to remember the next time I need to enter a character this way.  Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CLEAN(x) function - it gets rid of all that guff, especially where you have a mix of 161, 160 etc.

Comment: no it doesn't. didn't work with 160 for sure.